# HTML5 Javascript API Intellisense support in visual studio

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010

I started playing with HTML5/CSS3 and the new JavaScript API

something i noticed in VS 2010 is it doesn't have any support for the new JavaScript API i was wondering if there is anything i can do about it

so in Vs2010 if i type :

```
     var canvas = document.getElementById('diagonal');
     var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
```

i don't get any intellisense for the "getContext" method etc..

i dont wanna write the code and compile and pray it works.

any idea how can i enable intellisense for new javascript ?

Comment: _'i dont wanna write the code and compile and pray it work.'_ No. The idea is to have a firm understanding of what it is you're writing - debugging finds our mistakes - such aided development can even be detrimental to our field.

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment but i meant mistakes like:
GetContext vs getContext etc.
its obvious what i mean...

Comment: Well, no amount of aided development in the whole wide world is going to stop those - we're human. Actually, on second thought '_i dont wanna write the code and compile and pray it works.'_ doesn't that actually typify Javascript development?

Comment: by the way, your question has nothing to do with javascript 1.8.5 - it is about APIs, used by javascript. Please, edit title.

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment, aided development doesn't hold us back any more than calculators. If I know how to do long division, I'm fine not wasting my time doing it without a calc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know you tagged VS2010, but the [Visual Studio 11 Developer Preview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/hh127353), and presumably the eventual RTM, [natively supports HTML5 intellisense](http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/whitepapers/whats-new#_Toc303354505), including support for canvas.

> IntelliSense for DOM APIs has been improved, with support for many new
>   HTML5 APIs including querySelector, DOM Storage, cross-document
>   messaging, and canvas. DOM IntelliSense is now driven by a single
>   simple JavaScript file, rather than by a native type library
>   definition. This makes it easy to extend or replace.

Answer (score 3):

vsdoc documentation for Canvas for Visual Studio 2010:

http://abstractform.wordpress.com/2010/02/18/canvas-intellisense-auto-completion-in-visual-studio/

Comment: +1, Exactly what I was looking for. I was about to start writing one myself, so I'm glad I found this.

Answer (score 1):

This artricle describes how to add intellisense.  The system looks pretty flexible. I think you'll need to download a special doc version of the JS API though.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798328.aspx

Here is another

http://blog.turlov.com/2010/05/leveraging-visual-studio-javascript.html