# HTML5 API aware (auto-suggest/code-assist) JavaScript Editor/IDE

Tags: html, api, autocomplete, editor

I am aware of HTML5 specifications like `WebStorage`, `IndexedDB` API etc are still in progress. However, does anyone aware of good JavaScript editor that is aware of HTML5 API and can provide good auto-suggest/code-assist. I have tried Eclipse HTML Web Editor, it does auto-suggest some but not all (e.g. `window.sessionStorage` but not `window.localStorage`, `window.indexedDB` etc). Aptana Studio 3 recognizes less than Eclipse HTML Web Editor. I prefer Eclipse based as I am working on Java environment (will only try [VS 11](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9051175/418439) as last resource).

Note: I am not looking for WYSIWYG/visual HTML5 tags editor.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Any good, visual HTML5 Editor or IDE?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637930/any-good-visual-html5-editor-or-ide?rq=1).

Comment: @titusn, as per my note, I am not looking for WYSIWYG/visual HTML5 tags editor, but HTML5 API like WebStorage, IndexedDB API etc

Comment: You are absolutely right. Nevertheless, the other topic includes a lot of answers that are about IDE's like Aptana and Eclipse, which is why I think the link should remain here.